# laravel 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: laravel

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `translations` add unique `translations_table_name_co
lumn_name_foreign_key_locale_unique`(`table_name`, `column_name`, `foreign_key`, `locale`))
```

I add this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

But nothing change , still getting this error

Answer (score 16):

You also need to update the `config/database.php` file for `mysql` connections from `'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'InnoDB ',`

> config/database.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            ...
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
            ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

Be sure to set the service provider correctly (I assume you are already doing it base on your shared code)

> app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

And remember to clear cache and configuration

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

For more info on this issue: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/901

Answer (score 2):

You can see 3 solution here https://youtu.be/EWZfHyNs08c or follow these

**Solution 1:**

Changing default engine to `InnoDB` from phpmyadmin did the trick for me.

I am using Windows + WAMP + Laravel 8, I updated

```
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

but still it was not working. I figured out that tables were being created with default engine `MyISAM`. I dropped the database (I was just setting up so I could afford to drop the database) and changed default engine to `InnoDB` from **Variables > storage engine**.

I run `php artisan migrate` again and it worked.

**Solution 2:**

As Javier Pérez Batista answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628140/4514022).

Both worked for me, I tried both ways.